# Why does `SecIdentityCopyCertificate` keep crashing when trying to copy a certificate for VOIP using URLSession in Swift?

Tags: swift, voip, keychain, urlsession

`SecIdentityCopyCertificate` not working it produce crashes. means not able to copy certificate from `identity` . i am doing it for `voip` .

[image]

```
//MARK: - URLSessionDelegate
extension ViewController : URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge,
                    completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
        var certificate: SecCertificate?
        guard let identity = self.identity else {return}
        SecIdentityCopyCertificate(identity, &certificate)
        let cred : URLCredential = URLCredential(identity: identity, certificates: [certificate as Any], persistence: .forSession)
        completionHandler(.useCredential, cred)
    }
}
```

i tried this code and others as well. but every code crashes on `SecIdentityCopyCertificate`.